# Traded a dollar for a Penney?

Tags: united-states, marriage-practices, new-york-state, 1800s-decade

My (very...) great grand-father Silas Carpenter married a woman by the name of Phebe Penn(e)y on 27 Mar 1804, likely in Pittstown, New York.

There's a family legend that states that Silas used to say something to the effect of:

> I traded a dollar for a Penny and it was the best trade of my life

owing to the fact that a marriage license cost a dollar.

I'm trying to figure out if this family legend could in fact be true, but I'm not finding a great source to find the cost of a marriage license in those days.

Is this true, and if not, is there another possible source (Pastor cost for performing ceremony, etc) that could result in this legend?

Answer (score 1):

Call and ask

Rensselaer County County Clerk: 9am – 5pm,
Phone:  (518) 270-4080, 
Fax:    (518) 271-7998, 
Location:   105 Third Street, Troy, NY 12180

or

Rensselaer Public Library
(518) 462-1193  http://rensselaerlibrary.org/

Comment: I very much doubt whether a county clerk or a public librarian would be able to tell you offhand how much a marriage license cost in 1804. They would probably have to due a considerable amount of research...

Comment: They just need to know which book to look in. The answer is there. The problem is whether they will take the time.